# How to set the path for css for django apps

Tags: css, django, registration

I understand that when in the settings.py under Templates 'APP_DIRS' is set to True, django will look for templates in the apps. However, in my case I would like to use a single style.css file for all apps. Specifically I would like to use it for [django-registration](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/quickstart.html). 
When I look in the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

and as result it cannot find it, even though in my base.html I set it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}style.css" />
```

so I would expect it to correcty find the stylesheet, which I put into the main folder of the project (not the app) /static.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated so I can have all apps and external apps such as django-registration access the same style sheet.

I put

```
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- at the beginning -->
...
<link href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

a the beginning of the file, but the stylesheet still has no influence. How can I best debug this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In your case `style.css` needs to be a static file so it needs to be in your 'static' folder (or wherever else you're storing static files, including in the apps).

You're writing the template incorrectly. It should look like this – base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %} <!-- at the beginning -->
...
<link href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

Then if your templates for django-registration inerit from base.html using `{% extends "base.html" %}`, your `style.css` should be loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. The stylesheet has no influence. How can I best debug this?

Comment: Are any of your other static files working? Django has pretty good documentation on static files, so check that out.  If the stylesheet is actually appearing, maybe it's a CSS issue.

Comment: I only managed to get it to work in referring to the style sheet with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "my_app/style.css" %}">`. What could be the reason for that? is there no way to put the style sheet in the root folder static instead of the one in the app?

Comment: Awesome. You got it working. As long as you put `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),`  in `STATICFILES_DIRS` in your settings.py file you should have the static files at a root directory called 'static'.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the case in my world